# TypeError in Python 3.11 when Using BasicModelRunner from llama-cpp-python

Tags: python, llama, llama-cpp-python

I'm currently taking the [DeepAI's Finetuning Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/finetuning-large-language-models-project/) and encountered a bug while trying to run one of their demonstrations locally in a Jupyter notebook.

**Environment:**

- Python version: 3.11
- Required packages:

  - notebook
  - lamini
  - llama-cpp-python (> 0.1.53)

**Issue:**

When attempting to run the following code:

```py
import os
import lamini

lamini.api_url = os.getenv("POWERML__PRODUCTION__URL")
lamini.api_key = os.getenv("POWERML__PRODUCTION__KEY")

from llama import BasicModelRunner

non_finetuned = BasicModelRunner("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf")

non_finetuned_output = non_finetuned("Tell me how to train my dog to sit")
```

I receive a `TypeError` at the last line:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

This error occurs when I try to pass a string to the `non_finetuned` BasicModelRunner object.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables `POWERML__PRODUCTION__URL` and `POWERML__PRODUCTION__KEY` were not properly set.